# How to pray for a Gentile?

Tags: tefilla

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Davening for a non-Jew](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6097/davening-for-a-non-jew)

When praying for someone who isn't Jewish, what is the proper method? Is there a special formulation for their name, if any?