# Can a non-jew submit names for Mi Sheberach?

Tags: tefilla, gentiles, mi-sheberach

Can a non-jew submit names for Mi Sheberach (either Jews or [non-Jews](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6097/phrasing-of-refuah-prayer-when-praying-for-a-non-jew))? On shabbat during the Torah reading?