# Father is sick but he's not Jewish

Tags: tefilla, gentiles, choleh-sick

My mother is Jewish and I was raised Jewish. My dad converted in the reform tradition and I know what that means. Recently he's become ill, I am scared of what that means. I am incredibly close with both of my parents. They have been married just over 45 years and I am struggling to come to grips with their mortality as they age. How do I daven for a non-Jew in times like these. To put it into context, my father is seeing an oncologist tomorrow and I have a good idea of the outcome. Any wisdom or guidance would be helpful.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6097/phrasing-of-refuah-prayer-when-praying-for-a-non-jew I hope he remains well and you cherish every moment with him, and your mother.

Answer (score 5):

The standard approach is to Daven for him as (name) *ben* (father's name) based on the Maharshal, although there are other customs.

See [here](http://www.ravaviner.com/2020/10/should-we-daven-for-president-trump.html?m=1) and [here](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/featured/1906641/harav-yitzchak-zilberstein-were-obligated-to-daven-for-president-trump.html) for example.

See also Yechaveh Da'as 6:60 for more on praying for a non-Jewish parent.

Wishing him a speedy *refuah sheleimah* and may you all share many more years of excellent health.

Comment: Thank you for your kind and quick answer.

Comment: My pleasure. And if you want to drop the name in the comments, I would be happy to Daven for him and I'm sure many of the other generous and helpful Mi Yodeya users would as well.

Comment: Agree. To clarify, his first or first and middle name and his father’s first name please.

Comment: Could you find this Maharshal for me. I couldn't when they were quoting it for Trump